# Recursion function logic friend of friend in a Graph

Tags: swift, recursion, graph

Hi I have this `json` file with these partial data, and I will be `user 1` in this example, and need to create a graph vertex and connect it to my user for all my friends and then create a vertex and connect my friend friends and so on.

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Me",
   "friends": [25, 24, 16, 8, 13, 12, 7, 15]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Anne Emerson",
    "friends": [3, 21, 4, 20, 24, 5, 7, 12, 18]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ashley Hopper",
    "friends": [2, 22, 10, 20, 25, 11]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Alba Gates",
    "friends": [2, 17, 21, 11, 7, 13]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Louise Pennington",
    "friends": [2, 23, 22, 15, 20, 24]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Shields Gilliam",
    "friends": [26]
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Freida Evans",
    "friends": [1, 4, 2, 9, 18, 17]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Noel Serrano",
    "friends": [1, 24, 18, 9, 16, 11, 23]
  }
]
```

I tried to write a recursion function that goes throw my field list which are users with these ID's `[3, 21, 4, 20, 24, 5, 7, 12, 18]` like in the example. and create a graph vertex for the User I'm at and connect it with its parent user. and keeps going throw all my friends first then goes throw my friend friends and so on until I discovered all of the friends related to my user weather its directly or indirectly.

Graph methods to use:

create a parent vertex (ME):

```
let me = graph.createVertex(data: "Me")
```

connect vertexes together:

```
graph.add(.undirected, from: me, to: user25, weight: 1)
```

User model:

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case friends
    }

    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var friends: [Int]
}
```

what I tried so far using nested loops:

```
for (index, i) in friends.enumerated() {
          print("i: \(i)")
            let getUserByID = datas.users.filter{ $0.id == index}
            for (index, i) in getUserByID.enumerated() {
                print(i.friends)
            }
        }
```

where `friends` is `let friends = [25, 24, 16, 8, 13, 12, 7, 15]`

The logic isn't hitting me yet and I wasn't able to achieve this in `Swift 5` can anyone help ?

Sample OutPut for my friends mutual list:

```
John Doe - edge distance: 2, Mutual friends: 5
Bob Kemp - edge Distance: 2, Mutual friends: 3
Bryce Holmes - edge Distance: 3
James Smith - edge Distance: 3
```

The list should be ranked firstly by edge distance and secondly
by number of mutual friends.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far. Also add a sample of the expected output

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok will do

Comment: So you just want a [BFS traversal of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal#Breadth-first_search)?

Comment: @Sweeper I have implemented Graph extension in my code, but before I can do BFS I have to create vertex and connect them with edges for each friend and then friend of friend right ? the missing link is how to pass by every friend then create a vertex and connect it to another vertex , if that makes since

Comment: Ah, so that's where you're stuck. You should edit your question to make that clear. I suggest that you make a dictionary, such as `[Int: User]`, to store which id corresponds to which `User`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you check the latest edits

Comment: @Sweeper can you check the latest edits